# Rsync - transfer a certain range of directories

Tags: design-patterns, range, rsync

I have a 12tb file directory that I'm wanting to transfer to a series of 4x 4Tb drives.

I'm wanting a way of telling rsync to only transfer up to 3Tb to each if the 4 drives, and to have it do it in order of file name, but to also exclude files starting with an _.

Example:
Drive 2 should only have folders D-H

But the directory looks like this

```
_old
_unsorted
0000
1111
2222
3333
Apple
Banana
Carrot
Dog
Eagle
Football
Golf
Helmet
Iglo
""Etc
```

Seeing rsync documentation I figured I'd have to manually tell it what range of folders I wanted it to move to each drive.

I tried doing this by telling it to exclude the folders I don't want, using the curly brackets to have multiple patterns.

`--exclude={"_*/","[0-9]*/","[A-C]*/","[H-Z]*/"}`

But it looks like it only excludes the first pattern and the rest are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The trick for this was to have each of the exclude patterns be part of a separate exclude statement.

```
--exclude="_*/" --exclude="[0-9]*/" --exclude="[A-C]*/" --exclude="[H-Z]*/"
```

to do this as an include option instead you could do it like this.

`rsync -Phavzrd --append-verify --delete-during --include="[D-G]*/" --exclude="*/"   SOURCE DEST`

this will exclude everything that's not specified in the include.